# Как обновить страницу без перезагрузки?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет,есть страница mail.php,нужно ее обновить без перезагрузки всей страницы с помощью ajax или jquery.Как это реализовать.В google ничего толкового не нарыл
Сейчас использую window.location.reload

```
echo'<a href="javasсript:window.location.reload()"><input type="submit" value="Обновить"/> </a>';
```

но часто при обновлении вылетает повторное сообщение в почте.
Вот сам полный код файла mail.php

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['refer']) || $_SESSION['refer'] == NULL) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != NULL &&
    !ereg('mail\.php', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    $_SESSION['refer'] = str_replace('&', '&amp;', ereg_replace('^http://[^/]*/', '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    header("Location: /konts.php?".SID);
    exit;
}
$ank = get_user($_GET['id']);
if (!$ank) {
    header("Location: /konts.php?".SID);
    exit;
}

$set['title'] = 'Почта: '.$ank['nick'];
include_once 'sys/inc/thead.php';
title();

// добавляем в контакты
if ($user['add_konts'] == 2 && mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_konts` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]'"), 0) == 0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_konts` (`id_user`, `id_kont`, `time`) VALUES ('$user[id]', '$ank[id]', '$time')");
// обновление сведений о контакте
mysql_query("UPDATE `users_konts` SET `new_msg` = '0' WHERE `id_kont` = '$ank[id]' AND `id_user` = '$user[id]' LIMIT 1");
// помечаем сообщения как прочитанные
mysql_query("UPDATE `mail` SET `read` = '1' WHERE `id_kont` = '$user[id]' AND `id_user` = '$ank[id]'");

if (isset($_POST['msg']) && $ank['id'] != 0) {

    if ($user['level'] == 0 && mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_konts` WHERE `id_kont` = '$user[id]' AND `id_user` = '$ank[id]'"), 0) == 0) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['captcha'])) $err[] = 'Ошибка проверочного числа';
        if (!isset($_POST['chislo'])) $err[] = 'Введите проверочное число';
        elseif($_POST['chislo'] == null) $err[] = 'Введите проверочное число';
        elseif($_POST['chislo'] != $_SESSION['captcha']) $err[] = 'Проверьте правильность ввода проверочного числа';
    }

    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    if (isset($_POST['translit']) && $_POST['translit'] == 1) $msg = translit($msg);
    if (strlen2($msg) > 1024) $err[] = 'Сообщение превышает 1024 символа';
    if (strlen2($msg) < 2) $err[] = 'Слишком короткое сообщение';
    $mat = antimat($msg);
    if ($mat) $err[] = 'В тексте сообщения обнаружен мат: '.$mat;
    if (!isset($err) && mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]' AND `time` > '".($time - 360).
        "' AND `msg` = '".my_esc($msg).
        "'"), 0) == 0) {
        // отправка сообщения
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mail` (`id_user`, `id_kont`, `msg`, `time`) values('$user[id]', '$ank[id]', '".my_esc($msg).
            "', '$time')");
        // добавляем в контакты
        if ($user['add_konts'] == 1 && mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_konts` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]'"), 0) == 0)
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_konts` (`id_user`, `id_kont`, `time`) VALUES ('$user[id]', '$ank[id]', '$time')");
        // обновление сведений о контакте
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users_konts` SET `time` = '$time' WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]' OR `id_user` = '$ank[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$user[id]'");

        msg('Сообщение успешно отправлено');
    }
}
/*----------------------------SPAM----------------------------------------------------*/
if (isset($_GET['spam'])) {
    $q = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id` = '".intval($_GET['idd']).
        "' LIMIT 1"));
    $msgrat = "[b]$user[nick][/b]|$q[msg] | От:http://softden.ru/info.php?id=$q[id_user]";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `spamus` (`id_user`, `id_kont`, `msg`, `time`) values('0', '1', '$msgrat', '$time')");
    msg("Ваша жалоба о спаме отправлена администрации. Спасибо");
}
aut();
err();

if ($ank['id'] != 0) {
    echo "<form method='post' name='message' action='/mail.php?id=$ank[id]&amp;$passgen'>"; ?>
    < br / > < /div>Сообщение:<br / > < textarea id = 'msg'
    name = 'msg' > < /textarea><br / >
        < script type = 'text/javascript'
    src = '/sys/js/emotion.js' > < /script>
<script type='text/javascript
    ' src=' / js / emotion.js '></script>
<img src=' / js / icon / toolbar_smile.png 'title='
    Смайлы ' id='
    get_smiles_but ' onclick='
    get_smiles()
    ' />
<a href="javascript:emoticon(' [b][/b]')"><img src="/js / icon / bold.gif " alt="
        Жирный "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[i][/i]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / italics.gif " alt="
        Наклонный "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[u][/u]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / underline.gif " alt="
        Подчеркнутый "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[s][/s]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / strike.png " alt="
        Зачеркнутый "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[size=ваша цифра][/size]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / size.png " alt="
        Большой "/></a>

<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[url=][/url]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / link.gif " alt="
        Ссылка "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[img][/img]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / img.gif " alt="
        Картинка "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[color=red][/color]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / red.png " alt="
        Красный "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[color=blue][/color]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / blue.png " alt="
        Синий "/></a>
<a href="
        javascript: emoticon('[color=yellow][/color]')
        "><img src=" / js / icon / eloy.png " alt="
        Желтый "/></a><br />
    <!--Окошко со смайлами, сначало оно скрыто (display:none): -->
    <div id='smiles_window' style='display:none'>
        <div id='directories_div'></div>
        <div id='smiles_div'></div>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <br />
<?
if ($user['level']==0 && mysql_result(mysql_query("
        SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `users_konts`
        WHERE `id_kont` = '$user[id]'
        AND `id_user` = '$ank[id]'
        "), 0)==0)
echo " < img src = '/captcha.php?SESS=$sess'
        width = '100'
        height = '30'
        alt = 'Проверочное число' / > < br / > \n < input name = 'chislo'
        size = '5'
        maxlength = '5'
        value = ''
        type = 'text' / > < br / > \n ";
echo " < input type = 'submit'
        value = 'Отправить' / > \n ";
echo" < /form>";

}   
echo"<a href=\"javascript:window.location.reload()\"><input type='submit' value='Обновить' / > < /a>";    
echo "<table class='post'>\n";
$k_post=mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]' OR `id_user` = '$ank[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$user[id]'"),0);
$k_page=k_page($k_post,$set['p_str']);
$page=page($k_page);
$start=$set['p_str']*$page-$set['p_str'];
if ($k_post==0)
{
echo "   <tr>\n";
echo "  <td class='p_t'>\n";
echo "Нет сообщений\n";
echo "  </td > \n ";
echo " < /tr>\n";

}
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]' OR `id_user` = '$ank[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$user[id]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $set[p_str]");
while ($post = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$ank2=get_user($post['id_user']);
echo "   <tr>\n";
if ($set['set_show_icon']==2){
echo "  <td class='icon48' rowspan='2'>\n";
avatar2($ank2['id']);
echo "  </td > \n ";
}
elseif ($set['set_show_icon']==1)
{
echo " < td class = 'icon14' > \n ";
avatar2($ank2['id']);
echo " < /td>\n";
}

echo "  <td class='p_t'>\n";
if ($ank2)
echo "<a href=\"/info.php ? id = $ank2[id]\
        ">".MultiColor($ank2['nick'], $ank2['ncolor']).
        "</a>".online($ank2['id']).
        "\n";
        else
            echo "[DELETED] (+$kont[count])\n";
        echo "(".vremja($post['time']).
        ")\n";
        echo "  </td>\n";
        echo "   </tr>\n";

        echo "   <tr>\n";
        if ($set['set_show_icon'] == 1) echo "  <td class='p_m' colspan='2'>\n";
        else echo "  <td class='p_m'>\n";
        if ($post['read'] == 0) echo '(Неоткрыто)<br />';
        echo "<span style=\"color:$ank2[mcolor]\">\n";
        echo output_text($post['msg']).
        "\n";
        echo "</span>\n";

        /*-----------------------------------SPAM and Delete mail----------------------------------------*/
        echo "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"/mail.php?id=$ank[id]&amp;spam&idd=$post[id]\"><img src='/js/icon/error.png' alt='SPAM' title='SPAM' WIDTH='20px' HEIGHT='24px'></a>\n";
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/delete.php?id='.$post[id].
        '"><img src="/js/icon/trash.png" alt="Delete"" title="Delete" WIDTH="16px"" HEIGHT="16px"></a><br />';
        echo "  </td>\n";
        echo "   </tr>\n";
    }

    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "<div class='foot'>";
    if ($k_page > 1) str("mail.php?id=$ank[id]&amp;", $k_page, $page); // Вывод страниц
    if ($ank['id'] != 0) {
        if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_konts` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]'"), 0) == 1) {
            $kont = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_konts` WHERE `id_user` = '$user[id]' AND `id_kont` = '$ank[id]'"));
            echo "<a href='/konts.php?type=$kont[type]&amp;act=del&amp;id=$ank[id]'>Удалить контакт из списка</a><br />\n";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='/konts.php?type=common&amp;act=add&amp;id=$ank[id]'>Добавить в список контактов</a><br />\n";
        }
    }
    echo "<a href='/konts.php?".(isset($kont) ? 'type='.$kont['type'] : null).
    "'>Список контактов</a><br />\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
```

Кто что может подсказать?

Comment: На ваш код смотреть страшно. Давайте так - что вам не ясно в этом [примере](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)?

Comment: alvoro,мне не нужна подгрузка с файла,мне нужно просто обновление странички без перезагрузки по принципу window.location.reload но без перезагрузки

Answer (score 2):

[[[[@Samosval](/users/22456/samosval)](/users/22456/samosval)](/users/22456/samosval)](/users/22456/samosval), вам нужно обновить всю страницу или контент её определенных элементов? Если второе, то откуда собираетесь обновлять: из базы, файла или другого источника? И последний вопрос - знакомы ли вы с Ajax, JS или jQuery?

**Обновление**

> просто обновление странички без перезагрузки

[[[[@Samosval](/users/22456/samosval)](/users/22456/samosval)](/users/22456/samosval)](/users/22456/samosval), тогда у вас есть два варианта:

1. Если нужно вернуть страницу к первоначальному виду, который был при её загрузке, то страницу можно закешировать. В принципе, если страница не гигантских размеров, то тут может подойти и Local Storage.
2. Если после перезагрузки должны быть видны какие-то изменения, то или обновление ajax-ом, или всё-таки физическая перезагрузка.

Comment: Поконкретней можно  с примером,я в ajax не силен вообще

Comment: @Samosval ajax позволяет обновлять конкретные блоки страницы не затрагивая всего основного, проще всего использовать библиотеку jQuery, т.к. она позволяет не беспокоиться о кроссбраузерности.
Тут (http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/the-load-method/) можно посмотреть пример простой загрузки контента из статической html странички. Вместо этой странички может быть файл php, который будет выдавать данные.

Comment: Можно же просто в переменную страницу сохранить.